# Return value of any()

Tags: python, any

I have a question about returning a value of the `any` function in Python.

Here is the code:

```
def check():
   for l in lines:
       ret = any(word in l for word in list)
       return ret
```

It only returns a bool, but I need the word which matched with the list.

For example:

If I have the string `"In school they're eating for lunch a lot of unhealthy food"` and the list `["lunch", "burger", "sushi"]` then I would need the word `"lunch"`.

Comment: Since you haven't specified - what should happen if there are multiple matches?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't with `any` or `all` directly, which is shame. Clojure has the same functions, but they return the first/last truthy value, which is really handy.

Comment: Is it intentional that you only check the first line in `lines`?

Comment: For every match i would like to know why it matched. If theres "lunch" 5 times in the string, i would like to know that it matched because of lunch 5 times

Comment: @qonsycodes then `any` is not the tool for this job anyway, because it is short-circuited to stop as soon as it finds the first match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.8, the assignment expression can be used to capture the *witness* that causes `any` to return `True`.

```
for l in lines:
    if any((x:=word) in l for word in list):
        return x
```

If `any` returns `True`, it is because the value of `word` (assigned to `x`) caused `word in l` to be true. `x` and `word` are bound in different scopes: `word` in the scope of the generator expression, `x` in the scope where the generator expression is defined.

Comment: Amazing. Just to confirm, this shouldn't break short-circuiting, right?

Comment: Correct; `x` is basically assigned a new value each time `word` is assigned. The value you return is the last value `word` took on before `any` stopped iterating over the generator.

Comment: It should be equivalent to `for word in list: if word in l: return word`.

Comment: A bit of a throwback to Python 2 days where list-comp/gen-expression variables "leaked" to the general scope :)

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for! Thanks